# Can de-ionized water be used instead of distilled water to prepare lead acid battery electrolyte?

Tags: batteries, lead-acid

I have a couple of Yuasa and Power Sonic conventional lead-acid bike batteries that I recently purchased for a very good bargain price from a seller. They are new and never used. But unfortunately, the seller did not have the battery acid packs in his possession. So, I have to end up preparing that myself.

I know that I'll need to prepare a 36-38% concentrated sulfuric acid solution (this is what manufacturers usually use) using my concentrated acid which is a 95-98% ACS reagent sulfuric acid.

Now I know that they usually use distilled water to prepare them. But I was thinking if it's possible to use ultrapure de-ionized water instead.

Comment: As a chemist, I say yes.

Comment: As an electrical engineer I say trust the chemist.

Comment: @EdV Thaks for the response. I was looking for assurance before I went ahead and prepared it since I didn't want to mess up the process. BTW which one is a better choice if you had to choose among them, distilled or deionized?

Comment: Yes but remember the order, add acid to water!

Comment: @JohnD Definitely, because the heat generated from this dilution of large quantities will be significant.

Comment: Isn't de-ionized water a step up from distilled water?

Comment: @DKNguyen I agree, unless you have some reason (not in this particular case, of course) to then go to sub-boiling distillation or purchase water that has been specifically prepared for a specialized purpose.  If the deionization system is working properly, then the resistivity is about 18.2 M\$\Omega \$ cm.

Comment: @The_Vintage_Collector Please see my comment to DKNguyen. I guess I would have a preference for *properly* deionized water: we always used it in our research and teaching labs and my field of chemistry (analytical, mainly) required minimizing impurity issues.

Comment: @EdV Yes, the resistivity of the ultrapure deionized water I'm going to be using is 18.2MΩ cm. The system is a Milli-Q Direct 16 from Merck.

Comment: Great! Then I strongly second what @JohnD advised. All the safety gear is essential and stir well (glass stirring rods are good) as you very slowly add the acid to the water.

Comment: Yes, all precautions will be taken. I've worked with concentrated acids like H2SO4, HNO3, and HCl. But only in very small quantities. Since this is going to be a substantial quantity I'll have a friend come over to help me out who is a lab chemist and get all the protective gear also along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either type will work (deionized [DI] or distilled.) Both have had most mineral contaminants removed; DI more so than distilled. DI however is overkill, as distilled easily meets acceptable contaminant limits for lead-acid batteries.

More here: https://www.trojanbattery.com/pdf/WP_EffectOfImpurities_0612.pdf

So, ask the battery maker who employs the chemist ;-)

Comment: (+1) Nice reference! I especially liked the thing about platinum as a water impurity!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. That was very informative. So, one manufacturer also suggests it is safe to use deionized water. In parallel, I had emailed Yuasa technical support two days ago to see what they have to say about this. Since one of the brands I have is from them. I just got a response a few minutes ago. Their engineer seems to suggest that I use only distilled water only. I guess maybe it's because that's what they use in the manufacturing process. But after reading the article you have added above and from @EdV response I'll go ahead with deionized water.